# Changing Label in only one Cell in Tableview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an issue with my app. I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it. It goes as follows.

I am trying to changing 2 label texts in each cell in the tableview.
It is label MODE, and label TIME.

I am sending a byte array from an Arduino that contains the data to display it. One by one I am sending this from the Arduino to see it displays nicely in the tableview. Everything works. But when I try and send a different byte array with a different MODE and TIME, it changes ALL the previous cells. Instead of only updating the new cells with the correct Mode and Time.

Here is my tableview code:

**UI Table View Data Source**

```
 @IBOutlet weak var recieveTableView: UITableView!

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return recievedArrays.count
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecieveCell", for: indexPath) as! RecieveTableCell
     cell.contentView.backgroundColor = cell.isSelected ? UIColor.darkGray : UIColor.white

     cell.rowNumber.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)." //You have to + 1 ,because cells are zero based.
     cell.modeLabel.text = "\(recievedModeType)"
     cell.timeLabel.text = "\(String(message))μs"

     return cell
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     print("touched")
     if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? RecieveTableCell {
         cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
     }
 }
```

**recievedModeType** is the MODE and **message** is the TIME.

I have a function that runs when the app receives bytes. So the recievedModeType does update every time I send different types of byte arrays. So in I sense its working like it should, but I am missing something crucial here. If anyone got an idea how I should do this, or give me some tips that would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I managed to fix it and will give answer eventually!

Comment: Can you please show your table update method?

Comment: receiveTableView.reloadData() runs every time there's a new byte array received

Comment: So you want to expand the table view rather than reload everything?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. When I get one data array it is showed in one row and cell in the tableview. When I get more I get more cells. The labels in the cell change depending on the Data array. But when I sent 50 of MODE A, and then one of MODE B, Instead of 50 cells showing Mode A I got 51 showing 51 MODE B. It replaced all the labels with the new one. But I found a fix for it, and will update answer in a bit

Comment: since you using `reloadData()` it will reload all cells and assuming you just store the latest values in `recievedModeType` and `message` it is correct that all cells have the same value. If you want different values you need to store the values in an array and fetch it depending on the index path.

Comment: Exactly @carsten ! Thats what I came to aswell. I knew [indexPath.row] was crucial I just didn't know how to do it, but I figured it out like you said with storing the values in arrays etc. Cheers mate, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding new property

```
var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?
```

and than call:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

You should not call tableView.cellForRow method in didSelectRowAt method.